# What sentence parts needs to be repeated here?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, adverbs, conjunctions, parallelism

What of the following is right?

"We need to find out..."

- "...how to lower the costs or *how to* produce more."
- "...how to lower the costs or *to* produce more."
- "...how to lower the costs or produce more."

Comment: I'd say all three are correct.

Comment: Related: [Do I need to add “to” in every clause in a this sentence?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48944/do-i-need-to-add-to-in-every-clause-in-a-this-sentence), [“To do this or do that” or “to do this or *to* do that”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51851/to-do-this-or-do-that-or-to-do-this-or-to-do-that), [Repeat the preposition in an “or” phrase, or not?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36339/repeat-the-preposition-in-an-or-phrase-or-not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be clear, only the first one will do. The other ones could be misinterpreted as *We need to find out how to lower the costs or need to produce more*.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Guffa.  You want to have a parallel construction, but unless you repeat the "how to" part, it will be unclear which parts are parallel.

This sentence makes it clear that the "how to" parts are parallel:

> We need to find out how to lower costs or how to produce more.

The parallel in these sentences could be "to find" and "to produce":

> We need to find out how to lower costs or to produce more.
>
> We need to find out how to lower costs or produce more.

Alternatively, you could clarify the parallelism in the last two constructions by using "either":

> We need to find out either how to lower costs or to produce more.
>
> We need to find out either how to lower costs or produce more.

Answer (score 1):

Disregarding grammaticality, I don't like any of OP's possibilities. Better would be...

**...how to lower costs or increase production**.

...which juxtaposes the two alternatives more clearly.