# "To do this or do that" or "to do this or *to* do that"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, infinitives, parallelism

I saw on the bottom of an email:

> To change your email preferences or unsubscribe from certain
>   messages, click here.

Is that correct or should it be:

> To change your email preferences or *to* unsubscribe from certain
>   messages, click here.

Comment: "To explore strange new worlds, to seek out new life and new civilizations, to boldly go where no man has gone before."

Comment: You should use jQuery.

Comment: Related: [Repeat the preposition in an “or” phrase, or not?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36339/repeat-the-preposition-in-an-or-phrase-or-not)

Answer (score 7):

Either is grammatically correct: eliding the *to* would be called *[ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_%28linguistics%29)*, and it is normal in English.  The second *to* is redundant when considering the previously supplied grammatical context.  Consider the following ellipsis:

> *Original:* To change your preferences or to change your subscription list, click here.
>
> *Ellipsis:* To change your preferences or your subscription list, click here.

Here, the second *to change* is redundant, and can grammatically be removed.  You could also omit the second *your*:

> *Ellipsis:* To change your preferences or subscription list, click here.

While either will (almost always) be acceptable, ellipsis is generally preferred because of efficiency.

Comment: Thanks! Is one preferred over the other? Is one more formal or used more often in different regions? or are they both always acceptable?

Comment: Neither will be condemned (unless the world happens to be much worse than I'd noticed), but ellipsis is usually better, unless you are trying to be very clear.  It's not a predominantly formal phenomenon, nor is it predominantly informal.  Also, as far as I know, there isn't much consistent dialectical difference as to ellipsis.

Comment: You can even cut one more word in most contexts. You can say, "To do this or that".

Comment: Ellipsis is really only frowned upon in cases where it could create ambiguity, IMHO.

Comment: @Karl: 'is'or should be'?

Answer (score 1):

Disambiguation. Please repeat the *to*; after all saving two alphabets does not count for efficiency.

Let the user not be taxed with a grammatical ellipsis. (I had a mind to say 'Let not the user...'), but why not make it simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be "to do this or to do that". This goes more with the flow and sounds proper.