# Repeating "to" and "will" in enumerations of verbs

Tags: grammar, prepositions, auxiliary-verbs, bare-infinitive

Should I use the second "will" in constructions like this one: "it will definitely help you and **will** make the text more readable"

And should I write "to" before every infinitive in enumeration, or only before the first one, e.g. "it helps to develop and test" or "it helps to develop and **to** test"? Could this example be influenced by the fact that "help" can go with to-invinitive and bare infinitive, and with other verbs the rule would be different?

Comment: One way to avoid the second will, if you will, would be to say something like "it will definitely help you, as well as make the text more readable".

Comment: Related: [Repeating “to” in a list of verbs connected by “and”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54221/repeating-to-in-a-list-of-verbs-connected-by-and) and [“To do this or do that” or “to do this or *to* do that”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51851/to-do-this-or-do-that-or-to-do-this-or-to-do-that)

Answer (score 7):

It is not necessary in your example sentence to repeat *will* but doing so serves to emphasise that there are two consequences: *this will happen and that will happen* (cf. *this and that will happen*).

If, on the other hand, one of the consequences itself contains the conjunction *and*, then it is advisable to repeat the *will* to avoid momentary ambiguity. So:

- It will definitely help you and your colleagues and will make the text more readable.

is preferable to:

- It will definitely help you and your colleagues and make the text more readable.

The same principles apply to the repetition of *to*.

Answer (score 0):

Should you?  I don't know, but you don't have to.
Unless it is for emphasis or clarification, you do not need to repeat "to-" or "will-" when listing items in a series where those items are the same part of speech.
If you say it for one, it applies to them all.  To eat, drink, and be merry.
But if you say it for two, good parallel construction would require that you say it for all.  To eat, to drink, and to be merry.

Comment: This is a great answer. I hope you will provide some supporting references for this recommended usage / style of writing.