# Is it correct to say "The carpenter will bring a hammer and be able to use it."

Tags: grammaticality

I'm sorry about the title - I'm not sure which rules of grammar apply to this question.

I'm trying to decide the correctness of the following sentences.

> 1) The carpenter will bring a hammer and be able to use it.
>   2) The carpenter will bring a hammer and will be able to use it.

Sentence 1) looks like it could be parsed incorrectly as:

> The carpenter will bring [a hammer] and the carpenter will bring [be
>   able to use it].

Sentence 2) could suffer from a similar parsing error.

Is either sentence grammatically correct, in that the sentence parses to the following?

> The carpenter will bring a hammer and the carpenter will be able to use the hammer.

Comment: Both work.​​​​​​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: The first sounds almost unnatural. The second is even worse. This is less a matter of grammar, but style, see *Garden Path Sentence*. If something is ambiguous that doesn't yet falsify its syntax. I'm sure a similar question has been asked a hundred times before, but I don't know exactly what key words to search for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Repeating "to" and "will" in enumerations of verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63081/repeating-to-and-will-in-enumerations-of-verbs)

Comment: I think the second is better than the first, actually.

Answer (score -1):

Neither have solecism, but I'd go with the former as it eliminates redundancy and maintains brevity.